# Nodejs Ajax Call

Tags: node.js

I was calling this function from javascript file. which was working perfect but now i want to call same function using Node js. please give me any alternate method. this function is use to insert data onclick event before.

```
function signup_validations_google(name_g,email_g,pass_g) 
{
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8000/uri?name="+name+"&email="+email+"&pass="+pass, true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        string=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("Registration successful");
    }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In node.js, you would generally use `http.get()` from the `http` module or `request()` from the `request` module.  I find `request()` is a bit easier to use:

```
const request = require('request');
let query = {name, email, pass};

request({uri: "http://localhost:8000/uri", query: query}, function(err, msg, body) {
    if (err) {
        // error here
    } else {
        // response here
    }
});
```

There are a zillion other possible options for the `request()` module [described here](https://github.com/request/request).